# Boto3: 's3.Object' object has no attribute 'md5'

Tags: boto3

[This guide](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/resources.html) needs to be updated, there is no md5 attribute in `Object`'s instance.

How do I get md5 from object, instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects don't really have a proper MD5, they have instead an ETag. For objects uploaded all at once, this is just a regular MD5. For multipart uploads, however, the ETag is not a simple MD5 digest. Regardless, you can access the etag with [`obj.e_tag`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.e_tag).

Answer (score 0):

From [this reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html) seems like we can get it by using `obj.get()['ETag']`.